# Interacting with VB6 client using hidden control in embedded web browser control

Tags: vb6, browser, integration

I'm having difficulty trapping a programmatically triggered click event on a hidden button control from a ASP.NET MVC 4 web app inside a VB6 thick client (which is using a web browser control).  I'm able to trap the click event itself using the following:

```
Private WithEvents WebDoc As HTMLDocument

Private Function WebDoc_onclick() As Boolean  

    Select Case WebDoc.activeElement.iD    
       Case "A"
         Do something

        Case "C"
          Do something else

    End Select

    WebDoc_onclick = True

End Function
```

And this works just fine if the control is visible.  But if the control is invisible:

```
<div class="HideBtnDiv">
   <input id="C" name="NoItems" type="button" class="BtnDiv" style="display:none"/>
</div>
```

and I try to trigger a programmatic click via one of the following:

```
    $("#C").('click');

    $("#C").trigger('click');

    $("#C").triggerhandler("click");

    $("#C").focus();
    $("#C").trigger('click');
```

I'm getting an empty string for the "id" attribute and as a result I can't distinguish which button was clicked.  This button serves no purpose other than to indicate to the VB6 app that a certain criteria has been met and that's the reason why I need it to be hidden.  Does anyone have any idea why the id is getting stripped?  Or is there any other way to communicate back to the client?

I've also tried filtering by element style using

```
Select Case WebDoc.activeElement.Style

    Case "display:none"
        Do something else

End Select
```

but it came back as "[Object]" so no luck there either.  Please let me know if there is a way around this.

Thanks,
Lijin

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have tried several ways of dynamically triggering the click event, but did you try the most obvious way:

```
$("#C").click();
```

???

But here is what I would do:

1- Make all of your buttons visible, by removing "`display:none`" from their style

2- Wrap the buttons you want to hide in a new DIV

3- Set "`display:none`" style in the newly created DIV

4- You can then trigger the `.click()` event of any button even if not visible by calling `$(id).click();`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Ahmad. Actually I meant .click() not .('click').  Sorry about that.

Anyway, I tried your suggestion and made the button visible and set the style of the wrapping div to display:none but the id attribute was still coming through as an empty string.

However, I did figure out another way to get this to work.  If I keep the wrapping div and button as visible and then focus and click when the condition is met and then do a hide(), my problem is resolved!

```
$("#C").focus();
$("#C").trigger('click');

$("#C").hide();
```

The button doesn't get displayed and VB6 still passes the id on the click event.  The weird thing is it requires the focus() call to still be made.  Without it, I'm back to square one.  Not sure if this is a bug.